# Calculate $(f^{-1})'(0)$ of $\int_{\pi}^{x} \cos(\cos x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Calculate $(f^{-1})'(0)$ if $$f(x)=\int_{\pi}^{x} \cos(\cos x)\,dx$$

How do I calculate the derivative in $0$ of the inverse function of that integral?

I can't integrate it and I think I don't have too. I thought about using the derivation rule of the inverse function but I'm kind of lost. I read about Bessel function in a similar question but never heard of it and I think its unneeded.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: DO NOT use Bessel functions.  First, find $a$ so that $f(a)=0$.  That tells you  $f^{-1}(0)$.  Next, remember how to compute $f'(x)$ without evaluating the integral.

Comment: How can I find a so that f(a)=0 if I don't have the integral? Thats the only thing I'm not getting…

Comment: You can compute $\int_\pi^\pi$ even if you do not know the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can use the fact that $$(f^{-1})'(0)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(0))}$$ Notice that $\cos\cos x$ is positive for all $x\in\Bbb R$, since $\cos x\in[-1,1]$ and the nearest zeros of $\cos$ are in $\pm\frac\pi2$.

Therefore, $f$ is a strictly increasing function, which does not leave much choice for what $f^{-1}(0)$ can be...

Comment: Ok I get almost everything. I understand that cos cos x postive is and therefore f strictly increasing and bijective. Thats the reason why the inverse function even exists in the first place. But I don't get it why I now know f^-1(0).. I mean I still don't know the integral and can't calculate f(x)=0, can I? Sorry if its a bit stupid but I can't wrap my head around this

Comment: @Seen What's $\int_{19}^{19} e^x\,dx$ ?

Comment: Ok got it. So the final solution would be $$(f^-1)'(0)=\frac{1}{cos(-1)}$$ right?

Comment: Yes, that should be it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm finally starting to understand differential equations